# Boot-repair in Win8.1/Ubuntu not working (Loads windows with no GRUB)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I just installed Ubuntu as secondary OS. I can chose Ubuntu from the restart (<kbd>shift</kbd> key pressed) on Windows and boot to Ubuntu, but if I choose just restart then GRUB doesn't appear.

I did the Boot-Repair method 3 times, but it's still loading windows without showing GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

So when I <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Reboot on Windows it shows the menu for "[Use a Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5hWs.png)" and from there I could choose the Ubuntu partition and after the reboot it loads GRUB.

So I started reading other questions/answers and I found a very long answer with different scenarios, I already tried most but not tinkering with the BIOS...

So I entered my BIOS and in the boot section I had this list:

1. USB Drive:
2. Windows Boot Loader
3. HDD:
4. to 8 many more...

So I give it a try; it's logical I think, that the HDD should be first. So:

1. USB Drive:
2. HDD:
3. Many more...
4. Windows Boot Loader

And that was it!!! Now it boots with GRUB2!